# How can I Unmarshal 2 different type for one struct attribute

Tags: go, struct, unmarshalling

I have 2 different APIs—one written in Nodejs connected to MongoDB and one in Golang.

I make an API call from Golang to the Node.js service to fetch some product metadata. In some flows, I populate one property that has a reference to another collection in metadata and returns as a JSON object; in others, I don't and returns as a string.

I get a JSON Unmarshal error when I set my struct as below;

```
Brand *struct {
        Id   string `json:"_id,omitempty"`
        Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    } `json:"brand,omitempty"`
```

I don't believe assigning type as **Any** is the best practice to tackle this problem.

How should I define my entity to support multiple types?

One retuns as JSON Object

```
Brand: { ... }
```

---

and one returns as string

```
Brand: '5f4ce4c7f78655de5807csa1'
```

Comment: You are correct, using `any` is not best practice. Instead you should declare a custom type that implements the `json.Unmarshaler` interface and use that as the type of the Brand field.

Comment: As you can imagine I'm very new to Golang is there any chance you can provide a sample code snippet or any reference links? @mkopriva

Comment: See the `UnmarshalJSON` implementation at the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753749/unmarshal-json-that-could-be-a-string-or-an-object/46756027#46756027

Comment: To answer your literal question: Either as `json.RawMessage` or as `any`. But what you probably want is to implement json.Unmarshaler.